# Ruby on Rails:Issue with MySQL lib in Rails 3 Project

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a Rails project up and running in my Server.I am using Rails 3.2.8 and Ruby 1.9.3 with MySQL database .I have installed Ruby on Rails in 32-bit System.

Now i am trying to setup Rails in another Server which is running in Windows Server 2008 R2 64-bit.

I have setuped Ruby on Rails in Server(same version as in my old Server) and tried to create a sample project with SQLite Database , it is working. But when i tried to create a Rails Project with MySQL database i am Getting some error .

My Project is created but when i tried to Run my project it is Showing some error,

```
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.11-x86-mingw32/lib/mysql2/mysql2.
rb:2:in `require': 193: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.   - C:/Ruby193/lib/
ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.11-x86-mingw32/lib/mysql2/1.9/mysql2.so (LoadErr
or)
```

I am using MySQL Community Server 5.6.14 64-bit.In my previous Server it was MySQL 32-bit.

I have also installed DevKit.

I have also copied the libmysql.dll file from MySQL\lib  to Ruby\bin folder, still i am getting error.

Is it a problem regarding 64bit archi..

How to solve this Issue.

Any help is appretiated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may need to find another gem.  From the error output above it's for 32-bit:

```
mysql2-0.3.11-x86-mingw32
```

Or try reinstalling the gem to see if it builds for 64-bit.

Comment: I have tried reinstalling the gem ,but i am getting the same error.Should i install Mysql 32 bit.Will it solve the issue.